# Hanoi Towers in MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, towers-of-hanoi

I would like to implement Hanoi Towers algorithm in MIPS assembly.

Rods are indicated by `A`, `B` and `C`.

Input is number of number of disks and output is the sequence of moves necessary to solve the problem.

For example:
If input is `3`, output should be:

```
A>C
A>B
C>B
A>C
B>A
B>C
A>C
```

I've managed to get the result with the numbers of the rods, i.e. `1>3` instead of `A>C`, with the following code:

```
.data

NewLine: .asciiz      "\n"
To: .asciiz      ">"

.globl main
.text  

main:

  li $v0, 5
  syscall
  add $a0, $v0, $zero 

  addi $a1, $zero, 1        
  addi $a2, $zero, 3        
  addi $a3, $zero, 2        
  jal hanoi1

  li $v0, 10            
  syscall

hanoi1:        

  addi $t0, $a0, 0  
  addi $t1, $zero, 1
  bne $a0, $t1, hanoi2
  li $v0, 1             
  move $a0, $a1
  syscall
  li $v0, 4         
  la $a0, To
  syscall
  li $v0, 1             
  move $a0, $a2
  syscall
  li $v0, 4         
  la $a0, NewLine
  syscall
  addi $a0, $t0, 0      
  jr $ra

hanoi2:

  addi $sp, $sp, -20

  sw $ra, 16($sp)
  sw $a3, 12($sp)       
  sw $a2, 8($sp)    
  sw $a1, 4($sp)    
  sw $a0, 0($sp)        

  addi $t3, $a3, 0      
  addi $a3, $a2, 0      
  addi $a2, $t3, 0      
  addi $a0, $a0, -1             
  jal hanoi1   

  lw $ra, 16($sp)
  lw $a3, 12($sp)       
  lw $a2, 8($sp)        
  lw $a1, 4($sp)        
  lw $a0, 0($sp)        

  addi $t0, $a0, 0      
  addi $t1, $zero, 1
  li $v0, 1             
  move $a0, $a1
  syscall
  li $v0, 4         
  la $a0, To
  syscall
  li $v0, 1             
  move $a0, $a2
  syscall
  li $v0, 4         
  la $a0, NewLine
  syscall
  addi $a0, $t0, 0      

  addi $t3, $a3, 0      
  addi $a3, $a1, 0      
  addi $a1, $t3, 0      
  addi $a0, $a0, -1             
  jal hanoi1 
  lw $ra, 16($sp)

  addi $sp, $sp, 20

  add $v0, $zero, $t5
  jr $ra
```

I tried to add labels such as:

```
PrintA:
  li  $v0, 4 
  la  $a0, A
  syscall
  jr $ra
```

And add `beq` to branch to the right label:

```
beq $a1, $t7, PrintA # $t7=1
beq $a1, $t8, PrintB # $t8=2
beq $a1, $t9, PrintC # $t9=3
```

But the program got into infinite loop, probably because I didn't handle `$ra` correctly.

So my problem is I can't figure out how to convert the rods numbers to letters.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `jr $ra` to return somewhere, you must first set register `$ra` with the address to return to, that's what `jal` is doing before branching, putting address of next instruction into `ra`.

I.e. to use this:

```
    beq $a1, $t7, PrintA # $t7=1
    beq $a1, $t8, PrintB # $t8=2
    beq $a1, $t9, PrintC # $t9=3
```

with the `PrintA/B/C` variants ending by `jr $ra` means, that if you would not want to print anything there the next instruction instead of the `beq` block would be `jr $ra` too, ending that code-flow.

You can then do it like this:

```
    move $a0, <number of rod (from)>
    # make sure you have current `ra` stored in stack to not lose it
    jal  print_rod    # will set ra to address of next line
    ... continue with printing "To" string
    ... and then you can reuse the same subroutine to display second rod
    move $a0, <number of rod (to)>
    jal  print_rod    # will set ra to address of next line
    ... do remaining things (? if any), restore ra, continue
```

And put the rod number to letter conversion inside the `print_rod` subroutine. Which then may look like 3x `beq` with three different tails and using `jr $ra` to return from each of the variant back into the code above, but if you think about it from math and assembly point of view, you are converting values [1, 2, 3] to letters [A, B, C].

There is `syscal, v0=11` "print character", and needs ASCII character in the `a0` as argument.

If you will check ASCII encoding table, you will see that letter `A` is encoded as value 65, `B` is 66 and `C` is 67. And your input is value 1, 2 or 3. In all cases to transform the numeric rod value into ASCII letter you need only to add +64 to it.

I.e. your current way of displaying rod number:

```
  li $v0, 1
  move $a0, $a1
  syscall
```

Needs just small modification:

```
  li     $v0, 11       # print character service
  addi   $a0, $a1, 64  # number to ASCII letter (1->A, 2->B, 3->C)
  syscall
```

And that's it, no branching (branching is generally slower than doing simple calculation like `addi`).

Your current source has different parts of code being identical to others, you want again to spend some time trying to realize which part of code are being different and keep only those, and use single code for the identical path, either extracting that identical code into subroutine (using it by `jal subroutine+jr $ra`), or rearranging the code flow to be like:

```
  # something to be done in every iteration
  # if (next_part_should_not_execute) branch to skip_part_2
  # part 2 of code - being run just under certain condition
skip_part_2:
  # if (next_part_should_not_execute) branch to skip_part_3
  # part 3 of code - being run just under certain other condition
skip_part_3:
  # part 4 of code, being run every iteration, unconditionally
```

That way you need still just single copy of "part 4" instruction in the source, but the parts 2 and 3 will be run only when certain conditions are true.